# Anyway to save podcasts on SD card instead of phone storage?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, podcast

The podcast app stores all podcasts onto the phone storage. Is there any way to save them to SD card? I don't see any option to change this setting.

Comment: Have you tried to change default place of saved items? Settings->Memory - there you will find default place for various types of files. The is a chance that the app uses the place defined in settings.

Comment: Yes, I have already checked on the podcasts settings page as well as Settings > System > Storage page. The Podcast app itself is installed on the phone's memory and cannot be moved to SD card, therefore I assume it will not let me save the podcasts also on the SD card. I don't see such option.

Comment: Can you check if the files you have downloaded via the app, appear in Music or other public folder?

Comment: They appear in Music folder.

Comment: Have you checked where are the new downloaded files placed or the old ones, after changing Settings > System > Storage? Generally after changes, the app should download new files to SD.

Comment: Like I stated, there is no option either in the Podcast app's settings or the Storage settings of the phone where I can change the storage location  from device to SD card for podcasts. If you see such option then please share the screen-shots. I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The newest updates let me choose SD card as default storage for music. This way all the podcasts now get saved to the SD card.

Comment: Seems more like a comment. Try to post it as a comment. Or have details of OS build and please have screenshots also.

Comment: Adding to what Aamir said, you can get to those settings, by going to:
**Settings App -> System -> Storage**, and then change **Music** (shown as a note symbol) from **"This device"** to **"SD Card"**, hope this helps.